# Convert Audio Output in Audio Input using Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

I am starting to learn mobile programming through a Flutter course, and I had the idea of an app to fulfill a need of mine. However, I'm not sure if Flutter has a library capable of that; I searched a lot and could not find it.

Below is a drawing of what I intend to do.

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFOyC.png)

Can anyone tell me if it is possible to do this with flutter or even pure development for android (then I'll start to learn this)? If you know the library, could you inform me? The apps in question are not relevant to this question, but they would be two very specific apps. The goal is for the app to work when activated and stop when deactivated, without the need for headsets.

I just wish someone with more experience could point me in the right direction.